# What is the meaning of map token while uploading an app on Windows Phone store?

Tags: windows-phone

I am using bing map service in my Windows Phone app.I have registered the app on bing site and get a

map key to use in app.But I want to know while uploading an app to windows phone store there is

a Map Token option on Number 4 position.

What is the purpose of that Map token and Is I have to get that map token to use map service in my app although i am using bing map key in my app and if yes then how

Answer (score -1):

Map token is a key which you will get while uploading application on market place. Below is the link which will guide you in details about this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn741528.aspx